# Can't type in notebook in version 10

Tags: front-end, bugs

After upgrading to version 10, I sometime get into the situation that I can enter nothing to the notebook. The Mathematica seems alive but it doesn't take any input from the keyboard. I tried to quit the kernel but problem persists. It's very frustrating because sometimes I'm in the middle of a time consuming simulation and suddenly I cannot interact with Mathematica. I have to restart Mathematica to make it work again.

I have been trying to isolate the problem but I'm never able to pin down the exact conditions that problem shows up.

Have you ever encountered this problem, and do you have some suggestions to pin down what cause this problem?

Here is a screenshot demonstrate this problem, it shows that I can't input in Mathematica notebook, even after the kernel is quit, but at the same time input in the TextEdit app works normally:

I also mentioned this problem about a month ago in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18462972#18462972).

[image]

I'm in OS X 10.10.1

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall again？

Comment: @bills Yes, it only happens in Mathematica. To eliminate the possibility of the wireless keyboard, I used the virtual keyboard shown above in the screenshot (I also tried the physical keyboard on my macbook air, still has problem for Mathematica). Also shown there that the input works normally in the TextEdit app.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I tried two days ago when I update to version 10.0.2. But the problem seems still there.

Comment: Perhaps not using 10.0.2?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Thanks but version 10.0.0 and 10.0.1 also have problem for me.

Comment: I notice that when you click on a letter, there is new white space? Did you somehow change the color of the input? (so it's white and invisible to us?)

Comment: @ChenStatsYu No. I guess the white space you are referring to was because of the low recording quality. You can see that there is nothing input by looking at the cursor position of Mathematica.

Comment: The same thing happened to me a couple of times (also on OS X). Quitting Mathematica and restarting it fixed it both times. Interestingly, when I quit, it put up a dialog to save a few of the notebooks, and there I could interact with it (to click on yes or no). Very strange.

Comment: Do you know about [How do I fix common problems by resetting the Wolfram System to its default configuration?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) and [OS X Mavericks: Reset your computer’s PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: I've noticed this a couple of times and figured it was another bug. I've also had V10 just refuse to work for me due to a non existent license id problem.

Comment: What OS are you using? In 10.8.5 it hasn't happened yet so this might be mavericks-specific